# Drupal Module is missing after Drupal upgrade

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am very new to Drupal. I have a running website on Red Hat Linux. I followed the following steps to upgrade to 8.9.9 https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-manually. In short I have done,

```
Select all the files in the top-level directory (also hidden files starting with a dot) as well as
 the 'core' and 'vendor' directories, and delete them. Be sure not to delete the 'modules', 
'profiles', 'sites', and 'themes' directories.
```

Now when I followed all steps and ran update.php I am getting,

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\LogicException: Service
 'dzango.twig.truncate_extension' for consumer 'twig' does not implement 
Twig\Extension\ExtensionInterface. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\TaggedHandlersPass->processServiceCollectorPass()
 (line 164 of /var/www/html/add-main/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/Compiler/TaggedHandlersPass.php).
    
    Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\TaggedHandlersPass->processServiceCollectorPass(Array, 'twig', Object) (Line: 97)
    Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\TaggedHandlersPass->process(Object) (Line: 140)
    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object) (Line: 789)
    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() (Line: 1335)
    Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 916)
    Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 477)
    Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 707)
    Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

I have found these things were missing after upgrade,

[image]

Do I need to run some composer commands after upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the upgrade document https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-manually misses very important part. After bringing the changes from composer.json never forget to run composer install/update/require. Rather then manually bringing all my changes from my composer.json to new one, I ran `composer require mypackage` with my required packages and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to update all packages

```
composer update -vvv
```